# Can we have proper italics rather than slanted text?

Tags: discussion, design

I visited the http://english.stackexchange.com recently and I couldn't but feel jealous at the nice italic font used over there. At this site, which is much closer to typography  we have a *slanted* font! Can the designers reconsider?

Comment: I might add that our type is a bit *too slanted*...

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that there is no italic variant of Lucida Sans.

Comment: Throwing in my 2¢ here... I would love to see a serif typeface here instead of Lucida Sans.  As much as I love the Lucida family (I've used Lucida Console for almost 15 years in terminal windows), the use of a sans-serif typeface here on TeX.sx frankly just doesn't feel very TeX-like to me.  I don't know how people feel about Palatino, but I think that might work well here.  Anything other than Times!

Comment: @Todd I for one would *not* like a serifed font face. The current sans serif look is very clean. What looks good on paper doesn't necessarily look good on a web page, IMO.

Comment: I guess I'm spoiled by the Mac UI (amazing font rendering and everything looks great on the screen).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Humanist_sans-serif_typefaces) lists several Humanist sans-serif fonts with true italics.

Comment: @ToddLehman I'm also using a Mac, so that's not the source of my disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

No, since talic sans-serif fonts are rare and TeX.sx uses a sans-serif font (of which there is no sans-serif variant).

Comment: I suggest to check, e.g., Myriad, a sans-serif font with a real italic variant.

Comment: @lockstep: I edited my answer: they are _rare_.

Comment: How about something like Georgia?