# If we can't have italics, can we at least have *less* slanted text?

Tags: feature-request, design, typography

Reading the question "[Can we have proper italics rather than slanted text?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/860/can-we-have-proper-italics-rather-than-slanted-text)", it seems that proper italics are impractical with a sans-serif font.

However, I still feel that the slant is a bit much; can something be done about this please?

Comment: Or a working italic, emm, slantic (?) correction …

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, it *is* possible to at least try to [control the amount of slant using CSS3 skew transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999015/adding-more-slant-to-italic-text), but honestly, I wouldn't want to try it — even if it works, it's likely to look pretty horrible on most browsers.

It seems much safer to stick to plain old `font-style: italic` and just let the browser / OS font renderer implement it as best as it can, given the available fonts.

What we (or, rather, the SE designer(s)) *could* do is switch from the current Lucida Grande / Lucida Sans / Tahoma font stack to some other set of font families that actually have proper italic / oblique faces rather than relying on automatic slanting.  I'm not going to offer any specific suggestions, but there should be several reasonable choices available on most systems.

Comment: ... I don't suppose the automatic slanting is guided by font metadata?